# jQuery version of Conveyor Belt Slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, gallery, slideshow

I'm looking for a jQuery version of the Dynamic Drive slideshow [here](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex14/leftrightslide.htm)

I have used the jQuery cycle plug in many times, but want to display more than one image at a time in a continuous scroll. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Take your pick: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/fresh-jquery-image-gallery-display-solutions/

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need it to be jQuery?  The one you post the link to is in Javascript which is just as crossplatform and crossbrowser as a jQuery one would be.

I have had a cursory look for any jQuery implementations anyway, but like you say, most people seem to just display one image at a time in their image carousels/slideshows.